# Only in VS code "No name 'QWidget' in module 'PyQt.QtWidgets'"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyqt5

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


##

logo_location = 'C:\\Users\\gbytt\\Dropbox\\[A] 공유폴더\\[E] VScode\\PyQt\\logo.png'

##

class MyApp(QWidget):

  def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()
      self.initUI()

  def initUI(self):
      self.setWindowTitle('Icon')
      self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(logo_location))
      self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
      self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  ex = MyApp()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Error appears as below

```
No name 'QApplication' in module 'PyQt5.QtWidgets'
No name 'QWidget' in module 'PyQt5.QtWidgets'
No name 'QIcon' in module 'PyQt5.QtGui'
```

But in IDLE it runs neatly without any errors.

Also, if you create a .pylintrc file and wirte 'extension-pkg-whitelist=pyQt5' and insert it, an error appears as shown below.

```
No name 'QApplication' in module 'PyQt5.QtWidgets'
No name 'QWidget' in module 'PyQt5.QtWidgets'
No name 'QIcon' in module 'PyQt5.QtGui'
Bad indentation. Found 2 spaces, expected 4
Bad indentation. Found 6 spaces, expected 8
Bad indentation. Found 6 spaces, expected 8
Bad indentation. Found 2 spaces, expected 4
Bad indentation. Found 6 spaces, expected 8
Bad indentation. Found 6 spaces, expected 8
Bad indentation. Found 6 spaces, expected 8
Bad indentation. Found 6 spaces, expected 8
Bad indentation. Found 2 spaces, expected 4
Bad indentation. Found 2 spaces, expected 4
Bad indentation. Found 2 spaces, expected 4
Module name "Framework" doesn't conform to snake_case nameing style
Missing module docstring
Constant name "logo_localtion" doesn't confrom to UPPER_CASE nameing style
Missing class docstring
Method name "initUI" doesn't confrom to snake_case naming style
Missing function or method docstring
Final newline missing
```

Comment: Even if the method is performed, there is an error as below.

Bad indentation. Found 2 spaces, expected 4
Bad indentation. Found 6 spaces, expected 8
..
Module name "Framework" doesn't conform to snake_case nameing style
Missing module docstring
Constant name "logo_localtion" doesn't confrom to UPPER_CASE nameing style
Missing class docstring
Method name "initUI" doesn't confrom to snake_case naming style
Missing function or method docstring
Final newline missing

Comment: The duplicate already solved the error related to PyQt and pylint, the other errors are indentation, etc. If you don't want to get an error then you can disable linting: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_disable-linting